# Analyzer reports memory leaks in ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: ios, networking

I am using the ASIHTTPRequest Library in my project. It works very well with iOS5.1 in an app using ARC. (files in this library use compiler flag -fno-objc-arc) However, when I run analyzer it shows multiple potential memory leaks, especially in  ASIHTTPRequest. I am a little reluctant to start making changes in this library, that is widely used, is quite complex and is working fine in my project.

Suggestions?

an example:

ASIHTTPRequest.m line 1515

```
// Find out how much data we've uploaded so far
```

[self setTotalBytesSent:[NSMakeCollectable([(NSNumber     *)CFReadStreamCopyProperty((CFReadStreamRef)[self readStream],       kCFStreamPropertyHTTPRequestBytesWrittenCount) autorelease]) unsignedLongLongValue]];
    if (totalBytesSent > lastBytesSent) {

Analyzer message:

call to CFReadStreamCopyProperty returns a core foundation object with a +1 retain count of
object sent autorelease message
object sent autorelease message
object leaked: allocated object is not referenced later in this excecution path and has a retain count of +1